# Are observables preferred?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Consider a simple situation where you need to filter an array. In the context of angular and rxjs we could use both JS `filter` method and RxJS `filter` operator.

```
//JS filter
let array = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
let result = array.filter(x => x == '2')[0];

//RXJS filter
const p = from(array);
let result: any;
p.pipe(filter(x => x == '2')).subscribe(x => { result = x; });
```

Is there a situation where the one method is preferred over the other? Should I try to mostly deal with rxjs observables when possible especially in the context of angular inner workings (tree shaking, etc.)

Comment: Try the RXJS one without the `filter` on there (or even invert the filter to `x != '2'`), and you'll see that subscribe is called once for each element in the array, which is often not what you want. The array `filter`, and `Observable` filter have separate uses depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera Absolutely not, this code is dealing with hypothetical scenarios. Code Review deals with concrete code in a concrete context. This question does not apply.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've recently started using CodeReview. I thought that would be a better place to ask this question. Again, sorry about this. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

Like always, depends on what you want to acheive.

For a very simple case (only needed at one place for the specific component) I believe it makes no big difference performance-wise.

Observables are good if deal with **composing**.

Imagine you have a service witch gets some data over an API (lets call it "DogsAPI)

DogsAPIService:

**getAllDogs(): Observable<>** -> get all dogs

```
getAllDogs(() => {
    http.get("/dogs/all");
})
```

**getAllDogsWithColor(color: String)** -> subscribes to getAllDogs, then filters list with color

```
getAllDogsWithColor(color: String) = getAllDogs()
    .pipe(
        map(dog => dog),
        filter(dog => dog.color == color)
    )
```

**getAllDogsWithColorAndFirstName(color: String, firstName:String)** -> subscribes to 
getAllDogsWithColor() and filters by firstName

```
getAllDogsWithColorAndFirstName(color: String, firstName:String) = getAllDogsWithColor(color)
    .pipe(
        filter(dog => dog.firstName == firstName)
    )
```

The component at the other end can subscribe to them and do other various operations on the stream if needed.

Usually the subscription happens via async pipe (a smart component passes the observable via "**your observable | async**" pipe so the subscription happens right there before the property is being used.

Comment: Assuming that `getAllDogs()` returns an `Observable<Dog[]>`, then I don't believe this would work.. The filter does not have access to `dog.color` because it been passed a `Dog[]`. You'd have to use `map` in conjunction with the array's `filter` function

Comment: You are right, just written some fast pseudo code. I will improve the example. Thanks for your comment

Comment: That won't work either: `map(dog => dog)` doesn't actually do anything, it's transforming the array into the exact same array. But the point is that the right function should be used for the job. If you want to filter an array, use the array `filter` function. If you want to filter the events (not the event values) from your `Observable`, then use the `Observable`s `filter` function. For something like an HTTP request that only emits 1 value, `filter` is pointless

Comment: I think not. Actually map(dog => dog) does a map on the array items and maps the array to items. Anyway that was not the point in my answer, just an implementation detail

Comment: It honestly doesn't. The `map` function is used to transform the value. Whatever is returned from `map` becomes the new value. Here, you're just returning the same value with `(dog => dog)`. My point is, to filter on the array you'd have to use the array `filter` function anyway

Comment: Because you are so annoyed by the map -> try it for yourself :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y7d2ad

Comment: That's because you're using `from`. It doesn't emit an array of Dogs like an HTTP call would, it emits once for each `Dog`, which probably wouldnt be much use with the async pipe if you wanted to display all of them. So `map` really isnt doing anything-- you're already starting with an Observable that emits many times. (The operator that would allow you to emit an array would be `of`)